# Reload controller variables in view

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, json, ruby-on-rails-3.2

In a rails application i am working on, i would like to refresh/reload the index method of my controller without refreshing the view.  For instance lets say i have this as my index:

```
def index
    @title =params[:title]   
end
```

And html.erb:

```
<script>
function changeField() {
  var newTitle = "Alerts"
  $.ajax({
    url: 'index?title=' + newTitle,
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: '',
    dataType: 'script',
    headers: {
      'X-CSRF-Token': '<%= form_authenticity_token.to_s %>'
    },
  complete: function () {
    alert('<%=@title%>');
  }
  });
}
</script> 

<button type="button" onclick="changeField()"></button>
```

The problem i am having is that it does not reload the @title variable on the view so i get the original title and not the new title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When page was loading alert('<%=@title%>') equals alert('first value') and after set a new value javascript code can't be reloaded. If you look html code you can see first value but not second

I think you can add this code to you controller

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html # index.html.erb
  format.js { render :json { :title => params['title'] || @title }.to_json }
end
```

and add to js code `success: function(data) { alert(data['title']) }`

Comment: I see what you are saying.  Do you know of a solution to this?  In other words is there a way reload the variable?